# Changing Router Password - Diff. Between ESSID/WPA2 Key and Login/Password?

Tags: router

My Verizon Fios router (this one:  [https://www.amazon.com/Verizon-Router-Actiontec-MI424WR-Rev/dp/B00QGDLA5Y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QGDLA5Y)) has a sticker on it listing:

Login|Password

and

ESSID|WPA2 Key

I've been told that after I reset my router to factory defaults (long story, but basically I seemed to have malware on both my home computing devices and the router intself) that I should change the default router password.

But, my question is what password are they talking about?

Is it the first or second line I listed above?  Or, maybe both??

Thanks so much for your help everyone!  Greatly appreciate it from a non-tech literature guy!

Comment: Hello, I'd suggest you to change the router password (number 1) so only you can connect to the control plane (. You can also disable WPS and change the WPA key(number 2) so only you and the people who know this key can connect to your Wi-Fi network. For questions related to know-how at a user level, I believe you should post on "super user" rather than here (IS). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The Login|Password is what you use to connect to the device for administration.

ESSID|WPA2 Key is what you and other users use to connect to the device as a WIFI access point.

Using the Login|Password, you should be able to change the ESSID and WPA2 Key.

ESSID is the "name" of the wifi, the WPA2 Key is the "wifi password".

Answer (score 0):

### Login|Password

These are the credentials you use to manage your router (you can navigate to it's login page by typing its address in a browser (192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.0 in many times), there you can change settings e.g. change WPA key, enable / disable wifi, manage internet connection...

### ESSID|WPA2 Key

SSID is the name of your wifi network, and WPA(2) key is the password required to connect to it.

---

It's generally recommended to change both password / key, otherwise others with a very basic knowledge on default passwords could connect to your device, best case just for using your wifi, but worst case to install malicious software.